# choosing return values from .Net MVC API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller

I've been working with Infusionsoft's API system in .Net and I find the ["selectedFields"](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-retrieve-a-contact) functionality to make a lot of sense.

I'm currently making an API system and would like to build similar functionality in.

I'm sure it's got a name but for the life of me I can't figure out what to search for in order to get some working examples.

My only solution is something like below

```
Data.DataDataContext _db = new Data.DataDataContext();
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult load(int id, [FromUri] string rtnValue)
{
    var property = _db.PROPERTies.Where(p => p.id == id);

    if (!property.Any())
        return NotFound();

    var returnProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var prop = property.FirstOrDefault();

    if (rtnValue.Contains("Id")) returnProperty.Add("Id", prop.id.ToString());
    if (rtnValue.Contains("Energy")) returnProperty.Add("Energy", prop.energy.ToString());

    return Ok(returnProperty);
}
```

Going to the url `/api/property/load/1/"Id","Energy"....` IS returning what I'd expect `[{ "Id": "1", "Energy": "45" }]` so it seems to be working in that regard. It's more an optimisation of my code. I'm sure that I can do this in a better way.

Ideally I want to add a `List<string>` to the passed `rtnValue` variable, but then I'm not sure how I can pass the values to the API then, instinct tells me the url would look like `/api/property/load/1/["Id", "Energy"]` but this comes back with an error.

Any help on how to better optimise this code would be awesome.

Comment: It's not so much the how to return. That's actually returning fine. It's allowing the user to choose the values that get returned from the DB

Comment: My mistake. I'm not aware of any way to do this that won't involve reflection. You can farm the reflection out to a helper method and do some caching to improve performance considerably, but short of that the only other way I know of would be to Generate/Compile a C# class on the fly and use that instead which would be even more of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

What about this...

API Format:

```
/api/property/load/1?rtnValue[0]=test1&rtnValue[1]=test2
```

Controller Method:

```
public IHttpActionResult load(int id, [FromUri] List<String> rtnValue)
```